# Workaround for PhoneGap, EXC_BAD_ACCESS on getDeviceInfo

Tags: cordova, exc-bad-access

I have encountered `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on `getDeviceInfo` for an app when **upgrading to XCode 5.1 and support iOS 7.1**

For **XCode 5.1 and iOS 7.1**, it is very strictly in memory management and it causes my PhoneGap application error on iPhone 5s (it works for all non 64 bit phones, just **error on 5S**).

I have researched and see  lot of peoples having the same issue but no solution found so far.

I downgraded the XCode back to 5.0.2 and build for 7.0, it **works perfectly on iPhone 5s 64 bit**

Comment: Do you resolve this issue? I have the same :(

Answer (score 2):

Please, look at this commit and patch the changes
https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-ios.git;h=82ce4f2

It works for me

p.s. I have found answer here http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2014/03/12/xcode-5-1-and-cordova-ios/