# Phonegap On Resume App Crash

Tags: ios, cordova, crash

Whenever my app is resuming from lock screen in iOS7, it is getting crashed. The problem is coming mostly in iOS7 devices and it is happening only when the screen is getting locked out automatically. When the I unlock the screen and press any html div or button in the app, the app crashes.
I already tried the solution posted here - 
[Workaround for PhoneGap, EXC_BAD_ACCESS on getDeviceInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22783541/workaround-for-phonegap-exc-bad-access-on-getdeviceinfo) . It doesn't work.

The Crash log is below -

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xbe4008d4
Triggered by Thread:  3

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38590a84 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3859087c mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2dc61554 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 152
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2dc5fcba __CFRunLoopRun + 858
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2dbca46c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2dbca24e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   GraphicsServices                0x329042e6 GSEventRunModal + 134
7   UIKit                           0x3047f840 UIApplicationMain + 1132
8   SkiWithMe                       0x0005f646 0x3f000 + 132678
9   libdyld.dylib                   0x384ecab4 start + 0

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38590838 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x384df0d0 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x384d961e _dispatch_mgr_thread + 34

Thread 2 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38590a84 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3859087c mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2dc61554 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 152
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2dc5fc74 __CFRunLoopRun + 788
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2dbca46c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2dbca24e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   Foundation                      0x2e6054bc +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 316
7   Foundation                      0x2e67ac32 __NSThread__main__ + 1058
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38609c5a _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38609bca _pthread_start + 98
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38607ccc thread_start + 4

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3 Crashed:
0   WebCore                         0x35b08dba WebCore::TimerBase::heapDeleteMin() + 30
1   WebCore                         0x35b08ca2 WebCore::ThreadTimers::sharedTimerFiredInternal() + 90
2   WebCore                         0x35b08c1e WebCore::timerFired(__CFRunLoopTimer*, void*) + 22
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2dc61e7c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 12
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2dc61a96 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 790
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2dc5fe1e __CFRunLoopRun + 1214
6   CoreFoundation                  0x2dbca46c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
7   CoreFoundation                  0x2dbca24e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
8   WebCore                         0x35b970c0 RunWebThread(void*) + 416
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38609c5a _pthread_body + 138
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38609bca _pthread_start + 98
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38607ccc thread_start + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38590a84 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3859087c mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2dc61554 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 152
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2dc5fc74 __CFRunLoopRun + 788
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2dbca46c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2dbca24e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x2cc395ae GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 126
7   libAVFAudio.dylib               0x2cc2dafc CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 176
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38609c5a _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38609bca _pthread_start + 98
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38607ccc thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  JavaScriptCore::BlockFree
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x385a2f38 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38609262 _pthread_cond_wait + 538
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3860a07c pthread_cond_timedwait + 40
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x2ebee55e WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 102
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x2ebee38c JSC::BlockAllocator::blockFreeingThreadMain() + 88
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x2ebeba68 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38609c5a _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38609bca _pthread_start + 98
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38607ccc thread_start + 4

Thread 6 name:  JavaScriptCore::Marking
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x385a2f38 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38609262 _pthread_cond_wait + 538
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3860a03c pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x2ed8caea JSC::GCThread::waitForNextPhase() + 74
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x2ed8cb44 JSC::GCThread::gcThreadMain() + 48
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x2ebeba68 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38609c5a _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38609bca _pthread_start + 98
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38607ccc thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x385a2f38 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38609262 _pthread_cond_wait + 538
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3860a03c pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   Foundation                      0x2e6055ba -[NSCondition wait] + 190
4   SkiWithMe                       0x000f3564 0x3f000 + 738660
5   Foundation                      0x2e67ac32 __NSThread__main__ + 1058
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38609c5a _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38609bca _pthread_start + 98
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38607ccc thread_start + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38590a84 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3859087c mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2dc61554 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 152
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2dc5fc74 __CFRunLoopRun + 788
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2dbca46c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2dbca24e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   Foundation                      0x2e5b8692 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 250
7   Foundation                      0x2e6094d4 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 76
8   SkiWithMe                       0x0011b610 0x3f000 + 902672
9   Foundation                      0x2e67ac32 __NSThread__main__ + 1058
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38609c5a _pthread_body + 138
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38609bca _pthread_start + 98
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38607ccc thread_start + 4

Thread 9 name:  WebCore: CFNetwork Loader
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38590a84 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3859087c mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2dc61554 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 152
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2dc5fc74 __CFRunLoopRun + 788
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2dbca46c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 520
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2dbca24e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   WebCore                         0x35be00a2 WebCore::runLoaderThread(void*) + 250
7   JavaScriptCore                  0x2ebeba68 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38609c5a _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38609bca _pthread_start + 98
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38607ccc thread_start + 4

Thread 10 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x385a3440 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2dc65456 __CFSocketManager + 482
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38609c5a _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38609bca _pthread_start + 98
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38607ccc thread_start + 4

Thread 11 name:  WebCore: LocalStorage
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x385a2f38 __psynch_cvwait + 24
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38609262 _pthread_cond_wait + 538
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3860a03c pthread_cond_wait + 36
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x2ebee530 WTF::ThreadCondition::timedWait(WTF::Mutex&, double) + 56
4   WebCore                         0x35ccb344 WTF::PassOwnPtr<WTF::Function<void ()> > WTF::MessageQueue<WTF::Function<void ()> >::waitForMessageFilteredWithTimeout<bool (WTF::Function<void ()>*)>(WTF::MessageQueueWaitResult&, bool (&)(WTF::Function<void ()>*), double) + 104
5   WebCore                         0x35ccb2ca WebCore::StorageThread::threadEntryPoint() + 162
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x2ebeba68 WTF::wtfThreadEntryPoint(void*) + 12
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38609c5a _pthread_body + 138
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38609bca _pthread_start + 98
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38607ccc thread_start + 4

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x385a3c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38607e06 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38607cc0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x385a3c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38607e06 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38607cc0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x385a3c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38607e06 _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38607cc0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x800004f8    r1: 0x3e4003e0      r2: 0xbe4008d8      r3: 0x00000040
    r4: 0x02b1c3c0    r5: 0x04602e74      r6: 0x04602e74      r7: 0x02d0308c
    r8: 0x16dc6528    r9: 0x0f9000f8     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x16dc64d0
    ip: 0x38940808    sp: 0x02d0307c      lr: 0x35b08ca7      pc: 0x35b08dba
  cpsr: 0x20000030
```

Answer (score 0):

i think u have a issue when ur app back in foreground from the background ,so  it's happens due to when u r trying to access some data or array on background to foreground.that var or array wont accessible or u defined dynamic value thats why it's cause crashed .

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I'm having the same issue right now. We've isolated it down to the CDVConnection plugin and the onResume method/event.

Comment: I'm having the same issue too. Did someone find out more about it?